# A list check before and after concatenation with different results

Tags: list, haskell, boolean, concatenation, predicate

I have an assignment and the code is really simple to understand but I cant find a possible solution. Thats the code:

```
lucky:: [Integer] -> Bool
lucky (xs) = all (/=13) xs

catenate as []     = as
catenate as (b:bs) = b : (catenate as bs)

test_luck1 as bs = lucky as && lucky bs
test_luck2 as bs = lucky (catenate as bs)
```

So the question is: For which input(the same for both functions) are the boolean values of both functions different, for example the first one true and the second one false or vice versa. So the first function tests both lists individually and the second tests the concatenation of the lists. I have been thinking all day yesterday and have absolutely no idea. Could you guys help me with finding the trick that should be used to solve the question?

Comment: Have you looked at boundary cases?

Comment: No, I have not. What exactly do you in mind?

Comment: Try to, for example, evaluate `all (const False) []`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For infinite "lucky" `bs` and "unlucky" `as`, `test_luck1` will terminate, while `test_luck2` will not.

The functions test the values in different order, due to the (somewhat weird) implementation of `catenate`, which prepends `bs` to `as`.  Thus, `test_luck1` tests `as` first, then `bs`, whereas `test_luck2` tests `bs` first, and then `as`.

P.S.  This can be seen as a boundary case, as per @Mark Seemann's remark -- sorry for the spoiler ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: but the question ("Boolean values of both") presupposes termination in both cases.

Comment: @Will Ness:  You have a point.  I all but started explaining how there was no way to produce different boolean values, then got carried away exploring the broader context.  I missed the point, in a way, but I've no regrets about that :)

Comment: Of course, if you want to avoid the 'luck' factor, just interleave the lists and call `lucky` on that.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this some more, I think I was too quick on the trigger with my comments. Apart from shinobi's answer, I don't see any way in which the two functions would return different results.

Not that this *proves* anything, but I wrote a QuickCheck property to verify the hypothesis that `test_luck1` will always return the same result as `test_luck2`:

```
prop :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> Bool
prop as bs =
  test_luck1 as bs == test_luck2 as bs
```

I've been running this property with 1,000,000 tests, and they all pass, so I don't think that there's any 'normal' values of `as` and `bs` that will cause the output of `test_luck1` to be different from the output of `test_luck2`.